# f2py erf function lnk2019 unresolved external symbol error

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am trying to use f2py with command :

```
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --fcompiler=g95
```

My Fortran file is :

```
module test_f90

implicit none

real *8 :: delta

contains

subroutine test_f(val, r)
    real*8, intent(out) :: val
    real*8, intent(in)  :: r
    val = 0.5*( 1 + erf(r/delta) )
end subroutine

end module test_f90
```

But I have got this error :

```
test_fmod.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __g95_erf_r8 rÚfÚrencÚ d
ans la fonction _test_f90_MP_test_f
_test_f90.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes non rÚsolus
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.e
xe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\P
Cbuild /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PC\VS9.0 /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Pytho
n27\PCbuild /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PC\VS9.0 /EXPORT:init_test_f90 build\temp.win32
-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90module.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Releas
e\build\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\test_fmod.o
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90-f2pywrappers2.o /OUT
:_test_f90.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f9
0.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90.p
yd.manifest" failed with exit status 1120
```

If I substitute the line `val = 0.5*( 1 + erf(r/delta) )` by `val = 0.5*( 1 + sin(r/delta) )` f2py works well. So the problem is due to the `erf` function but I don't know why. I thought `sin` and `erf` were the same kind of function?

Comment: I can compile a simple program with `erf()` in G95 so my first conclusion was wrong. The compiler does contain this function.

Comment: I was even able to compile a simple f2py module in Linux using `f2py -c erf.f90 -m erf --fcompiler=g95 --f90flags="-fPIC"`. I have g95 version `gcc version 4.0.3 (g95 0.93!)`. Please check your version.

Comment: Try to compile a simple program with your g95 please: `print *,erf(1.d0); end`

Comment: I have just tried your program and it works well. I have gcc version 4.1.2 and g95 0.93.

Comment: `real*8 ` is not standard conforming Fortran. It has never been part of the ISO Fortran standard and it's not portable. Use a named constant to control the `kind` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use gcc 4.1.2 with g95 0.93 to make this succeed, as reported by OP.